# Smallest Primary Cell

Tags: batteries

I'm trying to find the smallest possible primary cell (preferably lithium). I've come up with the CR927, which is still a little bit big, and the CG-320, which is unfortunately a bit too long. It's for an ultra low power RTC backup, so only needs ~5mah. It would be great if the biggest dimension was 5mm, but its OK if it's up to 10mm as long as the other dimensions are <5mm.  Does anyone have any suggestions on batteries, or where to find them? I've tried looking but there doesn't really seem to be a big battery list. Failing that, how easy is it to get custom battery samples?

Edit: The operating voltage is 1.5-3.6V, but small enough batteries can be stacked.

Comment: What is your voltage requirement? Look at hearing aid batteries. They tend to be tiny.

Comment: How about a pair of SR416 cells stacked? 4.8mm x 1.6mm each gives you 4.8 x 3.2

Comment: Have a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_battery_sizes and then look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_battery_sizes#/media/File:Button_cells_and_9v_cells_(3).png

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using hearing aid batteries. Size 10 and size 312 may meet your requirements:

[image]

Generally hearing aid batteries hover around 1.4V, so depending on your application you may need to stack them. Not sure of the effect stacking them has on long-term reliability though.

Comment: Do you have any info on the self-discharge rate of those? I'm getting mixed info on the web, but this application needs a >5 year battery life, and these seem to be mainly designed for a few weeks. Lots of websites suggest that the batteries die quite soon after they get unsealed.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't, though I'm sure it's out there. There are plenty of graphs showing the discharge rate under load but I haven't really looked for self-discharge charts. Honestly your best bet would be to find a way to make a larger battery fit. That would be far more reliable

Comment: Unfortunately this is the absolute maximum size, which is a bit annoying.

Comment: @BeB00 I use these batteries all the time and their lifetime is VERY SHORT. They will self-discharge and need to be tossed away, whether or not they are in use. Once that colored tab is removed and they are exposed to air. I think 2 weeks is about as long as I've seen. (Of course, my experiences are limited and I don't know about everything in the world.)

Comment: @jonk Yikes, had no idea it was that bad. Thanks for the info

Comment: @DerStrom8 Yeah. 5 years will be a bit of a stretch. ;)

Comment: @jonk Heh, guess so! =P